# Spring eval url Veracode issue in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, veracode

I have a JSP page where I am getting URL from a property file like below -

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('url.home')" var="homeUrl" />
```

and it is used like below -

```
<a target="_blank" href='${homeUrl}'>
  <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

I am getting veracode issue CWE-80 (Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page) for `href='${homeUrl}'`.

What would be a better way to fix this Veracode issue?

Comment: what is the value of your url.home?

Comment: It could be any url, lets say `www.example.com?q=xyz`

Comment: Try changing single quote to double quotes for `href='${homeUrl}'`

Comment: @Abhijeet How will it make a difference?

Comment: Maybe single quotes is causing expression evaluation failure for href

Comment: There is not any failure. Everything is working fine.
There is *Veracode scan issue* CWE-80
So I need to change the approach. Most probably some encoding required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario use jstl tag e.g.

```
<a target="_blank" href="<c:url value='${homeUrl}' />">
  <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

Comment: After this change, Veracode scan is passed. Thanks :-)